# Not sure of the reason for output value

Tags: perl

I have these two statements in a perl code that I'm trying to understand.

```
our $CSITOOLS=`/x/eng/csitools/netapp_menu/common/csitools.sh`;
print "${CSITOOLS}\n";
```

Output:

```
/x/eng/csitools
```

How does `${VARIABLE_NAME}` work? (In this case `{CSITOOLS}`)

Thanks!

Comment: Your package-global `$CSITOOLS` (see [our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html)) receives the output of the `scitools.sh`, which runs under backticks.  Apparently, the output is what you show.  Run it from the command line, should give the same. Btw, you don't need those `{}`, there is no problem with `$VAR_NAME`.  They are needed to separate the variable name from other strings, like `${VAR_NAME}_more...`

Comment: I meant when interpolated, `"${VAR_NAME}_more..."`. See answer by [PerlDuck](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5830574/perlduck)

Comment: @zdim thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Are you sure it printed only part of the value (/x/eng/csitools) and not the whole string (/x/eng/csitools/netapp_menu/common/csitools.sh)

Comment: @SrihariKaranth Notice the backticks. `/x/eng/csitools/netapp_menu/common/csitools.sh` is __executed__ and the __output__ of that script is returned and stored in `$CSITOOLS`. So there's nothing wrong with `/x/eng/csitools`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors):

> As in some shells, you can enclose the variable name in braces
>   to disambiguate it from following alphanumerics (and underscores).

That is:

If you have a variable like `$foo` and you want to interpolate that whithin a string:

```
my $string = "This is $foobar";
```

then Perl would look for the variable `$foobar`. To make clear your variable's name
is just `$foo` you need to write

```
my $string = "This is ${foo}bar";
```

This is the way to *delimit* the variable's name. In your particular case the curlies `{}` aren't needed because `"$CSITOOLS\n"` already is unambiguous. However, it does no harm.

Comment: `perldata` was what I was looking for :)

Comment: @stevieb I had to search as well :-) Sometimes it's `perldata`, sometimes it's `perlsyn`. But perhaps the question was about the backticks and we were both wrong.

Comment: perldata pertains to variables and literals. perlsyn pertains to statements incl flow control statements and flow control statement modifiers.

Comment: thanks @ikegami . I was thinking of perlvar, but of course, that's more for special variables

Answer (score 3):

Perl allows you to surround the name of a scalar variable with braces (`{}`) to separate its name from any surrounding characters. Imagine you have the word "item" in a variable, and you want to print `item99` within a string, with no whitespace in between:

```
my $name = "item";
print "${name}99\n";
```

Without the braces, perl would interpret the variable like this:

```
print "$name99\n";
```

...which is an undeclared, undefined variable, and definitely not what you mean. With `warnings` enabled, would display something like:

```
Use of uninitialized variable in ...
```

If warnings are not enabled, the program may merrily run along and do other things, possibly/likely breaking something far down the line. That makes things really difficult to troubleshoot.

In your simple case, the braces aren't needed, and you don't see them all that very often in print statements, unless you need to combine variables where there's no whitespace character between it and other valid variable characters when interpolating within a string.

Answer (score 2):

From perldoc.perl.org

> A string enclosed by backticks (grave accents) first undergoes double-quote interpolation. It is then interpreted as an external command, and the output of that command is the value of the backtick string, like in a shell.

Apparently, the result of `csitools.sh` is the string `/x/eng/csitools`